# Not enough storage

Tags: iphone, photos, storage

I have an 8GB iPhone. I've had not enough storage for a while so I went through my photos and deleted 100. I also deleted old notes that I don't need. I also deleted an app of 81.5 MB. I tried downloading an app of 22.1 MB but it's telling me I don't have enough storage. Is this a bug or do I just not have enough storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have just not deleted enough items to make enough space for the app. Go back and check your storage again.

Apple is pretty good on the Storage section of Settings and it is almost always quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you delete photos or apps, try rebooting your phone by lock + home buttons and then you will see changes... i always do that :) hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough IOS devices don't always free up space when stuff is deleted, sometimes you get some savings but I have found that if you backup your IOS device (password protect the backup so it saves your passwords) erase all content and settings and then restore you will likely get back a lot of your "missing" space.